# Valuation at a prime ideal

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, dedekind-domain

I'm having troubles understanding the following definition

[image]

Can somebody help me understanding that definition? What is for example the power of an ideal?

Comment: $I^2=I\cdot I$ and so on. That's the power of  an ideal.

Comment: Note also that in the local ring, every ideal is a power of $\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: But how can one find the exponent such that the ideal is that power of p?

Comment: @HeiHei The exact method will depend entirely on what $R, \mathfrak p$ and $I$ are.